# Power BI - star schema - how do I resolve hierarchy in dimension tables?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling, datamodel

I have a star schema where I have 3 dimension tables that have a hierarchy

country 1---* County 1----* city

The star currently looks like this:

Country ----

County ---      FACT TABLE

City ---

so all three dimension tables link to the Fact table, but not to each other. I've read that it is bad practice to link dimension tables to each other, but not having the dimension tables linked to each other means that I can't filter City Dimension by Country dimension. Does anybody know what the best practice would be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Country/Region/City Data Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812170/country-region-city-data-model)